# get the avatar url instead of an html img tag when using get_avatar?

Tags: avatar, gravatar

i want to get the user avatar URL to use it as background URL style for a div. i tried to use the following but it does not return anything when i view the code it appears like that.

```
background: url()
```

i used this function.

```
function get_avatar_url($get_avatar){
preg_match("/src='(.*?)'/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
return $matches[1];
}
```

any help please??

Comment: Where is the `$get_avatar` variable coming from?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to construct the Gravatar URL yourself, it's just an MD5 hash of the user's email address.

```
<?php $gravatar = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(strtolower($email)) . '&s=32'; ?>

<div class="avatar" style="background: url(<?php echo $gravatar ?>);" ></div>
```

The `s` parameter at the end there defines the size of the image in pixels.

[Using Gravatars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars) - *WordPress Codex*

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
add_filter(
    'get_avatar',
    'get_avatar_url',
    10,
    5
);

function get_avatar_url( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size = 96, $default = '', $alt = '' ) {

    preg_match( '#src=["|\'](.+)["|\']#Uuis', $avatar, $matches );

    return ( isset( $matches[1] ) && ! empty( $matches[1]) ) ?
        (string) $matches[1] : '';  

}
```

Apply a filter on `get_avatar`, it takes 5 arguments (!). The first one is the complete `<img>`-tag. And do not forget the source can be enclosed with double **and** single quotes ( `["|']` ). I guess that was the point where your function failed.

Answer (score 1):

As of WordPress version 4.2.0, we can use [get_avatar_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/). The function can be found in `wp-includes/link-template.php`:

```
function get_avatar_url( $id_or_email, $args = null ) {
    $args = get_avatar_data( $id_or_email, $args );
    return $args['url'];
}
```

So you can simply use it by:

```
$avatar_url = get_avatar_url($user_id);
```

Also, I know this is an old question, but a **great lesson to be learned**. Always use prefixes when you add your custom functions. Your custom function is `get_avatar_url()` and so is the newly added core function `get_avatar_url()`. You would have received an error when you upgraded to 4.2.0.